# Google Dataflow streaming inserts to BigQuery hitting rate limits

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to use Dataflow streaming processing to insert records into BigQuery using Python. Changed files in a storage bucket are read from PubSub then the files are read, transformed and inserted into BigQuery.

However when the pipeline gets to processing around 100 to 200 elements/sec I get errors like the below that I'm exceeding a rate limit and linking to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors). Sometimes the errors mention the `tabledata.list` quota, which is 500/sec.

I don't understand why I'm seeing messages about these quotas at all though, as the streaming inserts quota for BigQuery is 1,000,000/sec.

```
> [while running 'generatedPtransform-52321']

        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MoreFutures.get(MoreFutures.java:57)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.finish(RegisterAndProcessBundleOperation.java:332)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:85)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1350)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:152)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1073)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error received from SDK harness for instruction -52327: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 883, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 498, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1024, in process
    schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1009, in _create_table_if_needed
    additional_create_parameters=self.additional_bq_parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 226, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 712, in get_or_create_table
    found_table = self.get_table(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 226, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 480, in get_table
    response = self.client.tables.Get(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/bigquery/bigquery_v2_client.py", line 581, in Get
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bought-by-many/datasets/mongo_landing_zone/tables/service_user_users_users?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 25 Feb 2020 16:49:25 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '403', 'content-length': '560', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Exceeded rate limits: too many api requests per user per method for this user_method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Exceeded rate limits: too many api requests per user per method for this user_method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 167, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 223, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 352, in do_instruction
    request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 386, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 812, in process_bundle
    data.transform_id].process_encoded(data.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 205, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 302, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 304, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.Operation.output
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 178, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 657, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 658, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 878, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 885, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 941, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 883, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 497, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1028, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 178, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 657, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 658, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 878, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 885, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 941, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 883, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 497, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1028, in apache_beam.runners.common._OutputProcessor.process_outputs
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 178, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.SingletonConsumerSet.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 657, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 658, in apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 878, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.receive
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 885, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 956, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/future/utils/__init__.py", line 421, in raise_with_traceback
    raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 883, in apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.process
  File "apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 498, in apache_beam.runners.common.SimpleInvoker.invoke_process
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1024, in process
    schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py", line 1009, in _create_table_if_needed
    additional_create_parameters=self.additional_bq_parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 226, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 712, in get_or_create_table
    found_table = self.get_table(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 226, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_tools.py", line 480, in get_table
    response = self.client.tables.Get(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/bigquery/bigquery_v2_client.py", line 581, in Get
    config, request, global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 731, in _RunMethod
    return self.ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 737, in ProcessHttpResponse
    self.__ProcessHttpResponse(method_config, http_response, request))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 604, in __ProcessHttpResponse
    http_response, method_config=method_config, request=request)
RuntimeError: apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpForbiddenError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/bought-by-many/datasets/mongo_landing_zone/tables/service_user_users_users?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 25 Feb 2020 16:49:25 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '403', 'content-length': '560', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Exceeded rate limits: too many api requests per user per method for this user_method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Exceeded rate limits: too many api requests per user per method for this user_method. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors",
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

The code I'm using is below:

```
    files = (
        p
        | "read PubSub"
        >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
            topic=known_args.input_topic, with_attributes=True, id_label=id_label
        )
        | "decode message" >> beam.Map(lambda pubsub_msg: json.loads(pubsub_msg.data))
        | "filter buckets with unknown encodings"
        >> beam.Filter(no_encoding_bucket_filter, encodings)
        | "get file from bucket" >> beam.ParDo(GetFileFromBucket())
    )

    policies = (
        files
        | f"filter for policies"
        >> beam.Filter(lambda msg: 'policies' in msg["bucket"])
        | f"encode policies"
        >> beam.Map(apply_encoding, encodings['policies'], 'policies')
        | f"filter out policies that failed to encode"
        >> beam.Filter(lambda item: True if item is not None else False)
        | f"insert policies to BigQuery"
        >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            project=project_id,
            table="service_policy_policies",
            dataset="mongo_landing_zone",
            insert_retry_strategy="RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR",
        )
    )
```

`beam.io.WriteToBigQuery()` does work with streaming data, but from the errors I suspect it's initialising or getting the BigQuery table as an object for every element thats processed, rather than just inserting a row. Am I using it in some incorrect way?

---

**Update 2020-03-11**

I managed to improve, but not resolve the situation. I switched from using `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` to writing a custom class called `WriteToBigQueryCustom` to do the same thing. I still get errors but only at 500/sec throughput or higher now.

Updated code:

```
class WriteToBigQueryCustom(beam.DoFn):
    """
    Stream insert records into a BigQuery table. Intended to work the same way you'd
    expect beam.io.WriteToBigQuery to work for streaming.

    Even though beam.io.WriteToBigQuery supports streaming, it seemed to be
    initialising the BigQuery connection for every element processed. Was
    getting throttled and causing errors about hitting BQ api limits at throughput of
    100 elements/sec when the streaming inserts limit is 1,000,000/sec.
    """

    def __init__(self, project_id, dataset, table_name):
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.table_name = table_name
        self.table_id = f"{project_id}.{dataset}.{table_name}"

    def start_bundle(self):
        self.bq_client = bigquery.Client()
        self.table = self.bq_client.get_table(self.table_id)

    def process(self, dict_to_insert):
        """Insert a dict to the classes BigQuery table"""
        errors = self.bq_client.insert_rows(self.table, [dict_to_insert])
        if errors:
            logging.error(
                f"Hit error uploading row to bigquery table {self.table_id}: "
                f"{errors}. Was trying to insert dict: {dict_to_insert}"
            )
```

Comment: You might ask this question in user@beam.apache.org. There people could give better answer on why "tabledata.list" API is used.

Comment: thanks, I've sent an email there now

Comment: Did you start the dataflow job using user account credentials (those obtained on your machine by running `gcloud auth application-default login`)? There's a message displayed in the console when you start a job this way that this isn't a good practice, because you can run into quota limits sooner. If you are, you should start a job using a service account instead of a user account.

Comment: I was using a service account @MattWelke

Comment: @MarkM I have a similar custom class, aren't you considered that the start_bundle is getting called on every message?  I mean that the self.bq_client = bigquery.Client() is getting called on every message and I wasn't sure if that's a good idea

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same troubles you did, while running a similar pipeline. It seems there is some sort of bug in the Python/Beam SDK.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6831

Adding create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER helped in my case.

Regards
Michael